# Convert query between date to codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, date

I have a mysql query :

```
SELECT `percentage` FROM `discount_percentage` WHERE `agent_id`=$agent_id AND    `insurance_type_id`=$insurance_type and `entity_id`=$entity_id and `state_id`=$state_id AND CURDATE() between from_date and to_date
```

I want to change the CURDATE TO php function
But date(Y-m-d) is not working.

And how to change this to pure codeigniter?

Comment: have you tried `NOW()` instead of `CURDATE()`?

Answer (score 0):

**Updated code** Try below code lets me know if you get any problem

```
$currentdate=date('Y-m-d');
$this->db->select('percentage');
$this->db->from('discount_percentage');
$this->db->where('agent_id',$agent_id);
$this->db->where('insurance_type_id',$insurance_type_id);
$this->db->where('entity_id',$entity_id);
$this->db->where('state_id',$state_id);
$this->db->where('from_date >=', $currentdate);
$this->db->where('to_date <=', $currentdate);
```

Comment: are you sure about `where('$currentdate >='` ?

Comment: Not working: Message: Use of undefined constant to_date - assumed 'to_date

Message: Use of undefined constant to_date - assumed 'to_date'

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_array()

Comment: can you please share your table structure

Comment: Table Structure :

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `discount_percentage` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `agent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `insurance_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `entity_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `state_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `percentage` float NOT NULL,
  `from_date` date NOT NULL,
  `to_date` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

Comment: @humbleiam check my updated code  lets me know if you get any problem

Comment: @Anandjain : 
        $value = $this->db->row_array();

Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_array()